# Error: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python-3.8

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "qr2eeprom.py", line 41, in

```
if  not re.search( r"Colibri 2-D1C4-[0-9][0-9]00-[0P][0-9]", string ):
```

File "/usr/lib/python3.8/re.py", line 201, in search

```
return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
```

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

I am trying to run a python script on ubuntu terminal. I am getting the above error

Comment: What do you mean by "I tried the export on terminal"?  What permissions does the file `/home/sys/sys_utils/design/sys_abc.sh` have?

Comment: I am a begiiner for Ubuntu. So I googled and the following export command was popped up so I tried to change the path using export command..

Comment: The permission of the file is : -rwxr-xr-x 1 home home 1540 Nov 18 14:28 abc.sh

Comment: That's a different file. I don't see any `sys_` in the name.

Comment: the file name is 'abc' with .sh extension..

Comment: You posted `sys_abc.sh : command not found`

Comment: Ohh...I am extremely sorry for the typos/mistyping...but the file name is abc.sh

Comment: Can you add the relevant parts of your script `abc.sh` to your question and code-format the error? It looks like it might be trying `sudo cd /foo`, which will not work. If it does need sudo permissions, then it should probably be called with `sudo ./abc.sh`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.